# Matplotlib Qt Cursor not showing

Tags: qt, matplotlib

I'm using Mac OS X (10.11.16) with PyQt5 and Matplotlib. I'm embedding a MPL plot environment into a Qt application. I want two things that I can't work out how to do:

1. I want a crosshair cursor whenever I am hovering over the plots.
2. I want the plot to take up the entire allocated area (see image below).

I am coding it as follows:

```
self.fig = plt.figure()
self.fig.patch.set_facecolor('#000000')

self.ax = self.fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
self.ax.set_facecolor('#000000')
self.ax.title.set_color('#FFFFFF')
self.ax.xaxis.label.set_color('#FFFFFF')
self.ax.yaxis.label.set_color('#FFFFFF')
self.ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5,0.12)
self.ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(0.12,0.5)
self.ax.xaxis.label.set_size(20)
self.ax.yaxis.label.set_size(20)
self.ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
self.ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
self.ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
self.ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
self.ax.tick_params('both',which='both',length=7,width=1,pad=-30,direction='in',colors='#FFFFFF')

# Create a canvas widget for Qt to use.
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
# self.canvas.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor))
# self.canvas.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
# cursor = mpl.widgets.Cursor(self.ax, useblit=True, color='red', linewidth=2)

# Refresh the canvas.
self.canvas.draw()
```

Those 3 commented cursor lines are my attempts at doing this, but they do not seem to work.

And for my plot size I want the axes to extend all the way to the ends of the working area. This is a dynamically sized area. Is it even possible?

[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the question if you want to have the axes take up all space or the image. In the former case, use

```
self.ax.set_aspect("auto")
```

[image]

in the latter case use

```
self.ax.set_aspect("equal", "datalim")
```

[image]

I cannot reproduce the cursor issue though. All three options work fine for me

Comment: You sir, are a legend! That was perfect (the "equal" "datalim" options). As per the cursors, I'm kind of at a loss as to why it refuses to change the cursor. I'll look more into it another day. Thanks for all your help @ImportanceOfBeingErnest